# OnSeekBarChangeListener using Butterknife

Tags: android, seekbar, butterknife

how can i set OnSeekBarChangeListener for a seekBar using Butterknife? I don't want to use

```
   mySeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(myOnSeekBarChangeListener);
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`ButterKnife` currently does not support `@OnSeekbarChangeListener`.

Here is list of listeners you can use with `ButterKnife`:

```
  OnCheckedChanged
  OnClick
  OnEditorAction
  OnFocusChange
  OnItemClick
  OnItemLongClick
  OnItemSelected
  OnLongClick
  OnPageChange
  OnTextChanged
  OnTouch
```